# CheckBox gets converted to Button in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, actionscript-3

I am new to Flex, so please bear with me.

I have encountered a strange problem.
There's a ActionScript class which dynamically creates basic UI element.

So I create RadioButton as

```
var rBtn:RadioButton = new RadioButton();
```

and then put it in a Panel Container.

The problem is that it appears to be a Button. However it behaves like RadioButton.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/438cac93dd.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/438cac93dd.png)

I have found this problem with one more guy who has posted it here.
[CheckBoxes and RadioButton looks like Push Buttons](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/480943).

Please help me out with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Flex 3 or Flex 4?  Skin looks like Flex 3; but I wanted to be sure.  And did the solution on the thread you link to work?

Comment: It's Flex 3.The solution in the link at the end says to switch to MXML. But in my case I cannot. I feel there's some kind of implicit casting taking place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured what was going wrong here..

I was using `flash.utils.getDefinitionByName()` and also a MetaTag for my custom classes similar to `[Frame(extaclass="com.test.wizardContainer")]`

This meta Tag causes to have default style for any DisplayObject being created using `getDefinitionByName()`.

CheckBox and Radio Button being sub-class of Button as DisplayObject. The style of Button is applied onto them. However they have their own behaviour.

I got rid of `getDefinitionByName()` and it was working fine.

For those who doesn't want to get rid of getDefinitionByName.Tou can simply do the following.

Say your custom class is classes.MyRadioButton, then

```
import classes.MyRadioButton;

public class someClass{
MyRadioButton;
...
...
...
}
```

I hope this helps who are facing similar problems.